# Python 3.7 KeyError

Tags: python, keyerror

I like to retrieve information from NewsApi and ran into an issue. Enclosed the code:

```
from NewsApi import NewsApi
import pandas as pd
import os
import datetime as dt
from datetime import date


def CreateDF(JsonArray,columns):
    dfData = pd.DataFrame()

    for item in JsonArray:
        itemStruct = {}

        for cunColumn in columns:
            itemStruct[cunColumn] = item[cunColumn]

        # dfData = dfData.append(itemStruct,ignore_index=True)
            # dfData = dfData.append({'id': item['id'], 'name': item['name'], 'description': item['description']},
            #                        ignore_index=True)

    # return dfData
    return itemStruct

def main():
    # access_token_NewsAPI.txt must contain your personal access token
    with open("access_token_NewsAPI.txt", "r") as f:
        myKey = f.read()[:-1]
        #myKey = 'a847cee6cc254d8495632f83d5c77d39'

    api = NewsApi(myKey)

    # get sources of news
    # columns = ['id', 'name', 'description']
    # rst_source = api.GetSources()
    # df = CreateDF(rst_source['sources'], columns)
    # df.to_csv('source_list.csv')
    #
    #
    # # get news for specific country
    # rst_country = api.GetHeadlines()
    # columns = ['author', 'publishedAt', 'title', 'description','content', 'url']
    # df = CreateDF(rst_country['articles'], columns)
    # df.to_csv('Headlines_country.csv')

    # get  news for specific symbol
    symbol = "coronavirus"
    sources = 'bbc.co.uk'
    columns = ['author', 'publishedAt', 'title', 'description', 'content', 'source']
    limit = 500     # maximum requests per day
    i = 1
    startDate = dt.datetime(2020, 3, 1, 8)
    # startDate = dt.datetime(2020, 3, 1)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'author': [], 'publishedAt': [], 'title': [], 'description': [], 'content':[], 'source': []})
    while i < limit:
        endDate = startDate + dt.timedelta(hours=2)
        rst_symbol = api.GetEverything(symbol, 'en', startDate, endDate, sources)
        rst = CreateDF(rst_symbol['articles'], columns)
        df = df.append(rst, ignore_index=True)
        # DF.join(df.set_index('publishedAt'), on='publishedAt')
        startDate = endDate
        i += 1

    df.to_csv('Headlines_symbol.csv')

main()
```

I got following error:

```
rst = CreateDF(rst_symbol['articles'], columns)
KeyError: 'articles'
```

In this line:

```
rst = CreateDF(rst_symbol['articles'], columns)
```

I think there is some problem regarding the key not being found or defined - does anyone has an idea how to fix that? I'm thankful for every hint!

MAiniak

EDIT:

I found the solution after I tried a few of your hints. Apparently, the error occurred when the NewsAPI API key ran into a request limit. This happened every time, until I changed the `limit = 500` to `limit = 20`. For some reason, there is no error with a new API Key and reduced limit.

Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: As the error says `KeyError: 'articles'`. You are accessing a spot in the dictionary that doesn't exist. Make it exist.  `rst_symbol['articles'] = {}` or an object, w/e

Comment: Please read the documentation, https://newsapi.org/docs/client-libraries/python. `api.get_everything()` **not** `api.GetEverything()`, which seems to be a method name from other programming language.

Comment: Please provide the entire error message, as well as a [mcve]. Also, can you clarify what exactly the issue is?

Answer (score 0):

Probably 'articles' is not one of your columns in rst_symbol object.

Answer (score 0):

The `python` [documentation](https://github.com/mattlisiv/newsapi-python) [[2]](https://github.com/mattlisiv/newsapi-python/blob/master/docs/source/examples.rst) [[3]](https://newsapi.org/docs/client-libraries/python) doesn't mention any method named `NewsApi()` or `GetEverything()`, but rather `NewsApiClient()` and `get_everything()`, i.e.:

```
from newsapi import NewsApiClient

# Init
newsapi = NewsApiClient(api_key='xxx')

# /v2/top-headlines
top_headlines = newsapi.get_top_headlines(q='bitcoin',
                                          sources='bbc-news,the-verge',
                                          category='business',
                                          language='en',
                                          country='us')

# /v2/everything
all_articles = newsapi.get_everything(q='bitcoin',
                                      sources='bbc-news,the-verge',
                                      domains='bbc.co.uk,techcrunch.com',
                                      from_param='2017-12-01',
                                      to='2017-12-12',
                                      language='en',
                                      sort_by='relevancy',
                                      page=2)

# /v2/sources
sources = newsapi.get_sources()
```

Comment: I created the object class NewsApi and then read it in. I found the solution and put it into the original post! Thanks for helping me out!

Comment: You're welcome, glad you sorted it out, but you should post an answer instead of updating your question.